# Cannot deserialize instance of `Books` out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, rest-assured

Can anyone help me because i really don't know how to resolve my issue:

1. I have just simple GET request with such Array in response body:

```
  [
    {
        "bookingid": 12
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 8
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 25
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 6
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 29
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 20
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 17
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 22
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 30
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 26
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 3
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 2
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 18
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 14
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 9
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 11
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 4
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 13
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 15
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 19
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 7
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 5
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 21
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 24
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 27
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 33
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 31
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 1
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 23
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 28
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 32
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 16
    },
    {
        "bookingid": 10
    }
]
```

2. I'd like to just send a `GET` request by using Rest Assured with POJO Classes
3. My POJO Classes:

   3a. Books class with List object with Ids:

```
package pojo;
import java.util.List;

public class Books {
    private List<Ids> bookId;
    public List<Ids> getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }
}
```

4. Second class - Ids with ids of books

```
package pojo;

public class Ids {
    private String bookingid;

    public String getBookingid() {
        return bookingid;
    }
}
```

5. Test class:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class Books {

    @Test
    public void GetBooks() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking";
        given().when().get().as(Books.class);
    }
}
```

When i'm running this test i have error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `Books` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[{"bookingid":10},{"bookingid":21},{"bookingid":4},{"bookingid":9},{"bookingid":14},{"bookingid":2},{"bookingid":19},{"bookingid":15},{"bookingid":5},{"bookingid":3},{"bookingid":12},{"bookingid":7},{"bookingid":20},{"bookingid":1},{"bookingid":16},{"bookingid":17},{"bookingid":13},{"bookingid":6},{"bookingid":11},{"bookingid":18}]"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deserialize to list of Book Ids.

This

```
 given().when().get().as(Books.class);
```

should be

```java
given().when().get().as(Ids[].class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see many issues here:

1. You test class and outermost POJO are both called `Books`. Which one are you trying to deserialise to?
2. In the input JSON the key is named `bookingid` and in the code it is `bookingId` (notice the uppercase `I`.
3. Why do you have an outer class `Books` (as POJO) at all? From the format of the JSON it seems more logical just to deserialise to array of `Ids` and since this represents a single ID then it should probably named `Id`.

Comment: Hi @Tarmo...indeed. Thanks for the response. I changed all things according to your answer(s) and now it is working